# How to get the best children for each parent document in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, parent-child

I use a parent/child relationship to store some documents:

```
{
    "A" : {
        "properties" : {
        }
    }
}

{
    "B" : {
        "_parent" : {
            "type" : "A"
        },
        "properties" : {
        }
    }
}
```

In my use case I need to find the best `B` document for each `A` document. (Like a `has_parent` query and some filter which ensures that only the highest scored document for each parent is returned.)
Is there a nice solution for this problem?

Comment: The question is not clear enough, can you provide a short example of your data ?
Basically, you can use the "has_parent" query to get child document (B) base on condition of parent (A), and the results will be ranked base on A fields (boosting at index time, at query time..)

Comment: The problem with "has_parent" is that I can't limit the number of children which will be returned for each parent. (I want only the highest match.) Example: document `A` is some sort of advice (text) and document `B` is the translation of `A`. There are multiple translations `B` for each advice `A` and it's possible that there is more than one translation for the same language (one `A` has two `B` for German). 
Now I want to search for the best (one) translations `B` which match with some rule for `A` and score `B` based on there language (first German, then English) (and other stuff).

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I need to implement a really similar scenario.

Comment: No, I haven't found a nice solution yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you found a way to do this?

If not, once v1.4.0 of ElasticSearch will be released, you should be able by combining two aggregations :

1. A [`children` aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-children-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-children-aggregation) (will be included in 1.4.0) based on the parent type A
2. A [`top_hits` aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) (added in 1.3.0) with `size` 1 to retrieve only the best matching child.

Comment: Children aggregation hasn't been released yet.

Comment: Thanks Dan, indeed : I didn't catch it. For those interested, here is the related [pull request](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/pull/6936). Answer edited.